# Finding the common ratio of a geometric series from the sum and first term

Tags: sequences-and-series

If the sum of a geometric series is 80, and the first term is 5, and the number of terms is 5, how can I determine the common ratio?

Comment: You end up with a quintic equation, I'm not sure if this one is solvable but [Solvable quintics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Solvable_quintics) might be of some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much brute-force.

Let r be the common ratio. Then $5+5r+5r^2+5r^3+5r^4=80$, so $r+r^2+r^3+r^4=15$. Now just use the series formula!

Comment: For $r+r2+r3+r4=15$, r doesn't equal 5. If r=2, $r+r2+r3+r4=16$, and if r=1, $r+r2+r3+r4=6$. The answer is somewhere in between 1 and 2. I would need to use brute force to find the correct number, by trying them until I find the right one.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure where I put the 5. I'll edit it.