# Find the ratio of a geometric series given a partial sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

How can I compute the ratio of a geometric series given a partial sum?
Basically solve for $r$:
$$ S = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} a\,r^k = a \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$
given $S$, $a$ and $n$
I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581546/finding-the-common-ratio-of-a-geometric-series-from-the-sum-and-first-term), but it just reduces the problem to the case $a=1$, and doensn't provide a solution for this one.

Comment: In general: you don’t, because it involves to calculate the zeroes of a polynomial of degree $n-1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is not what I hoped for but I know I should do things differently now!

Comment: Your formula is not correct ! It should read: $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} a\,r^k = a \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$.

Comment: @Fred : thanks for pointing it out, I edited the question